# Is it a best practice to validate the JWT payload after verifying?

Tags: jwt

**My question assumes the implementation of the JWT is sound, and it's more about what you do afterwards with the valid payload.**

I am issuing JWT tokens, and then each token is verified to confirm the identity of the user. But is it necessary to still validate the fields once the token has been validated?

For example, here's a sample token payload:

```
{
  “iss”: “example.com”,
  “exp”: 1426420800,
  “company”: “example”,
  “userid”: 123456789,
  "name": "Bob"
}
```

Do I need to validate that 'userid' is an integer? And validate 'name' is a string of a certain length?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do I need to validate that `userid` is an integer? And validate `name` is a string of a certain length?

Assuming that your JWT implementation is *sound* as you mentioned in the question *and* assuming that you trust the server that issued the token, such level of validation is not necessary after checking the signature.

---

Before accepting the token you must ensure that the token is valid. Here are some validations you must consider:

- Validate the signature to ensure that the token was not tampered with.
- Ensure that the token is not expired by checking the [`exp`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.4) claim.
- If you use the [`nbf`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.5) claim, ensure that it's not too early to accept the token.
- Validate other claims such as [`iss`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.1) if you need to.

Most of *sound* JWT implementations support those validations.

---

As mentioned in Lutz Horn's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50037859/1426227), you should rely on JWT for *authentication* (who the caller is) only. For *authorization* (what the caller can do), look up the caller roles/permissions from your persistent storage to get the most updated information.

Comment: This is great. Thanks for the write up!

Answer (score 2):

This depends on your server. If it will do anything using the JWT claims, for example store some data, it should validate that the executing user exists and is **authorized** to do this.

The JWT only handles **authentication**: Prove that the user is who he is and that he presented the necessary information (password) to prove this. JWT does **not** handle **authorization**: check what the authenticated user is allowed to do.

Comment: Thanks @lutz-horn, super helpful!